# Methods to count the number of monitors and basic info about each?

Tags: macos, pixel, multiple-monitors

Does OS X have any methods such as:

- `[monitors.count]` that return the number of monitors
- `[monitor.height]` that returns the number of pixels for the height of one monitor
- `[monitor.aspectratio]` that returns the aspect ratio of one monitor

(The above aren't actually methods, but that would potentially be what they would look like)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [NSScreen class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
//Number of monitors
[[NSScreen screens] count];

// Height of screen '0'
[[[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:0] frame].size.height;
```